# How to regress Y on X using matlab?

Tags: matlab, regression, linear-regression

Given :

```
Y=[81  55 80  24 78 52  88 45 50 69 66 45 24 43 38 72  41  48 52  52  66 89];

X=[124 49 181 4  22 152 75 54 43 41 17 22 16 10 63 170 125 15 222 171 97 254];
```

I want to regress `Y` on `X` (simple linear regression). I tried with this code :

```
b= regress(Y,X)
```

But it gives me this error :

```
??? Error using ==> regress at 65 
The number of rows in Y must equal the number of rows in X.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? If you're up to date then you should probably consider using `fitlm` instead of `regress`...

Comment: I'm using Matlab 7.10.0

Comment: That's 2010a if I'm not mistaken? So in that case it's much to old for `fitlm`. You should check if your license allows you to get the latest version though - there have been a lot of really worthwhile improvements since then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regress` expect its inputs as **column** vectors.
Transposing (`.'`) your inputs should do the trick:

```
>> b = regress( Y.', X.' )
b =
0.4291
```

Comment: I think you should reword this, `X` should not be a column vector but an *n*-by-*p* matrix where *p* is the number of inputs or explanatory or independent variables (in this case 1). Also worth adding a warning here the `regress` will not include an offset term unless you explicitly augment your `X` matrix with a column of `ones`